# Python - Why does iSlice and OrderedDict not write all contents of MS Excel to JSON?

Tags: python, json, excel, list, dictionary

I'm writing the contents of Excel into JSON.
I have 3 columns in Excel: Items, Quantity and Price.
It have 15 rows of data. With this code, it only writes the last row of Excel into JSON.
What's the issue here ?

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import islice
import openpyxl

# Open the workbook and select a worksheet
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\\Users\\Ricky\\Desktop\\NewStock.xlsx")
sheet = wb['ItemList']

# List to hold dictionaries
MyItem_list = []

# Iterate through each row in worksheet and fetch values into dict
myitems = OrderedDict()
for row in islice(sheet.values, 1, sheet.max_row+1):
     myitems['Item'] = row[0]
     myitems['Quantity'] = row[1]
     myitems['Price'] = row[2]
     MyItem_list.append(myitems)
print(MyItem_list)

# Serialize the list of dicts to JSON ... creates a json string
j = json.dumps(myitems)
print(type(j))  #j is of string object

# Write to file
with open('C:\\Users\\Ricky\\Desktop\\dataitem.json', 'wt') as f:
    f.write(j)
```

Comment: (1) You must create a new `OrderedDict` `myitems` for each row. Otherwise you only overwrite its previous content and append a new reference to the same `OrderedDict` to `MyItem_list` over and over again. (2) You convert only `myitems` to JSON which contains only one row (last one) instead of `MyItem_list`.

Comment: Thank you !.(1) I've added myitems=OrderedDict() in the for loop.  (2) used MyItems_list insread of myitems to convert into JSON. It worked.